# C++ formating doesn't work like expected in VSC

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, formatting

Starting today I've been having problems with my C++ auto-formatter in VSC.
Up until today when I saved the file I'm working on, any empty lines between code and the closing braces would automatically be removed, but now it's not working.

I'm using the `C/C++ Extension Pack` and `Better C++ Syntax` extensions.

*Example from how it used to work:*
Before saving:

```cpp
int main()
{
    int x;

    int y;



}
```

After saving:

```cpp
int main()
{
    int x;

    int y;
}
```

But now it just removes the empty inline spaces, where the cursor is, and keeps the empty lines, basically doing nothing.

I tried many configurations in [`.editorconfig`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/cpp-editorconfig-properties?view=vs-2019) and settings but it didn't help or I'm not understanding the options correctly. I thought about resetting the `.editorconfig` file but I couldn't find a version with all the default values for all the options.
I also tried uninstalling all C++ related extensions and reinstalling but it also didn't work.
Finally I tried using the extension `Remove empty lines`, but it removed all empty lines on the file and that's not what I'm expecting.

I'm wondering if an updated version of the `C/C++ Extension Pack` might have caused this or if I messed up some configuration somewhere.

Comment: weird. same day someone having opposite ask: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75533319/11107541

Comment: Do not tag C for C++ questions.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by removing the `.editorconfig` file in the directory of the project.
It was probably overriding the default configurations from VSC.